# Regex in java to validate a phone number does not work

Tags: java, regex

I would like to write a regex which allows to validate a phone number which can be written as follows: 237 698888888 or +237 658888888 or 67883888 ..., in fact the phone number must respect the following condition (+237|237)'Space'(6|2)(5|8|2|3|9|7|6) [0-9] {7}

If the user purposefull to enter a number with prefix the prefix must be 237 or +237 in the case otherwise he decides to enter a number without prefix in this case he must enter a number with 9 digits the first digit must be 6 or 2, the second digit must be between 2,3,5,6,7,8 and 9; And the 7 digits remaining to the choice ie [0-9] {7}. Here is my java code for:

```
String regex = "(\\+237|237)\" \"(6|2)(2|3|[5-9])[0-9]{7}";
String sPhoneNumber = "237 278889999";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sPhoneNumber);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    Log.e("|==FILTER_NUM==>>","Phone Number Valid");
}
else
{
    Log.e("|==FILTER_NUM==>>","Phone Number must be in the form XXX XXXXXXXX");
}
```

Returns this

> E/|==FILTER_NUM==>>: Phone Number must be in the form XXX XXXXXXXX

Please check my code and tell me what's wrong

excuse me for my English :)

Comment: So what is the issue? Your regexp works in the way you do not expect or your log messages starts with E/ ?

Comment: did you try to verify your regex from any online regex builders or testes?

Comment: What fails? Can you provide some examples of phone numbers that should be considered valid, but aren't?

Comment: I think my regex is badly written, because the number I passed in parameter is valid so `matcher.matches ()` is supposed to return true, but it returns me false.

Comment: @markusk Here is the example of valid phone number: +237 696989898, 237 223980987, +237 655999999, 237 677888888, 689000000, 237 696777777

Comment: you encoded the space badly in your regex `\" \"` - this way regex is trying to match quotes. use this regex instead: `(\\+237|237)\s*(6|2)(2|3|[5-9])[0-9]{7}`  where space (zero or more) is encoded as `\s*`

Comment: @kevinkemta Please edit your question instead of adding the additional information in a comment.

Comment: Thank you @diginoise my problem has been solved thanks to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex

```
(\\+237|237)\" \"(6|2)(2|3|[5-9])[0-9]{7}
```

You are using a space in it. use `\\s` instead to detect one space.

Also you can simplify this

```
\\+237|237
```

To

```
\\+?(237)
```

The final regex will look like

```
(\\+?(237))\\s(6|2)(2|3|[5-9])[0-9]{7}
```

Comment: Thank you ca walk very well also with your expression

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is searching for literal quote marks (`"`), which is causing the match to fail. Also, since the prefix is optional, you need to indicate this by following the prefix part of the expression with `?`.

The following regular expression should match all your sample phone numbers:

```
String regex = "(?:\\+?237 )?[26][235-9]\\d{7}";
```

Answer (score 0):

(\+237|237) [62][^014][0-9]{7} is the expression for more details you can refer [javaRegularExpressions](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). This is the online test of the expression [above code test](http://fiddle.re/0pxvnd).
for space just use space it will match space too.

Comment: Thank you ca walk very well with your expression

Comment: I am happy to help.